# Selenium Grid 3 node startup ignoring -nodeconfig node.json

Tags: selenium-grid

I'm just setting up a new Selenium Grid, and have just one node to register to my hub at the moment.  Both hub and node running on CentOS 7.  I have two different versions of Firefox on my node, and no other browser, as I will be setting up different nodes for different browser types.

If I start the node completely from the command line, specifying the different Firefox versions and locations, it all registers and starts properly.  On the Grid console page I see my node with the two versions of Firefox, 3 instances of each, correctly detailed with the version numbers I'm specifying.  This is the command line I use:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -hub http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,version=50.1.0,maxInsfirefox_binary=/opt/firefox-50.1.0/firefox,maxInstances=3,platform=LINUX -browser browserName=firefox,version=51.0.1,firefox_binary=/opt/firefox-51.0.1/firefox,maxInstances=3,platform=LINUX
```

If however I try using a .json config file to specify my parameters, the java startup completely ignores the config file and starts up using defaults; on the Grid console page it shows 5 Firefox sessions, 1 IE and 5 Chrome, and none of the Firefox sessions show the versions I'm specifying.  This is the command line invoking the json file:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -hub http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4444/grid/register -nodeConfig /opt/selenium/node.json
```

... and this is the node.json file itself:

```
{
  “capabilities”:
  [
    {
      "browserName": firefox,
      "firefox_binary": "/opt/firefox-50.1.0/firefox",
      "maxInstances": 3,
      "platform": LINUX,
      "version": 50,
      "seleniumProtocol": WebDriver
    },
    {
      "browserName": firefox,
      "firefox_binary": "/opt/firefox-51.0.1/firefox",
      "maxInstances": 3,
      "platform": LINUX,
      "version": 51,
      "seleniumProtocol": WebDriver
    },
  ],
  “maxSession”: 5,
  “port”: 5555,
  "hub": "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4444",
  “register”: true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "role": node,
  "cleanUpCycle": 2000
}
```

I have tried putting all parameters encased in double quotation marks, in case that was the issue; made no difference.

Any clues why the parameters in my node.json file are being ignored, please?

Comment: How are you concluding that its being ignored ? I used your JSON and I can see all the values that I provided via the JSON file. I confirmed this by opening up http://localhost:4444/grid/console and doing a mouse move over on the 2 firefox icons (I see the firefox bin path that I set)

Comment: I know it's being ignored because as I mentioned, the console is not showing my two specific Firefox versions, but instead is showing the default 5 Firefox, 5 Chrome and 1 IE icons.  It should only be showing my two specific Firefox instances, and nothing else - as the command line does.

Comment: Can you please try once again with the debug flag and using the JSON file that I have used in this gist post ( https://gist.github.com/krmahadevan/daf7d56b91c7681405f0bcfe387096f5 ) I have also included my console logs. Once you run your node in debug mode please share the console logs as well via gist.

Comment: Thanks @Krishnan, have replied on your gist post.

Comment: Helen : It might be because your JSON is not well formed.. for e.g., the platform is specified as LINUX but its not within quotes. In JSON there's either text (or) boolean (or) numbers. Maybe that is the reason. Can you try adding quotes to all text which is not numbers in your json and see if that's working ?

Comment: I did that to begin with, thanks Krishnan; it made no difference.

Comment: Helen : I guess I am now out of ideas.